# How to deal with a user who is harassing you by block questions?

Tags: discussion

My questions keep getting locked up whenever I put a bounty on them. How do I deal with this?  I feel as though I am being abused or just harassing as a novice.

Comment: Can you give us an example? Link us to a post?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56093/why-are-slayers-always-women-and-not-men

Comment: It was locked a few hours after i put a bounty on it, i had made no arbitrary changes to bump it up i just put a bounty and then he locked it

Comment: So you have a single example? The first step should have been to ask why that particular question was locked, not immediately jumping to claims of abuse or harassment.

Comment: He did it to another but had a point since i made arbitrary changes, the buffy one i had not made any arbitrary edits it was purely because i put a bounty on it

Comment: Fyi adding a bounty bumps the question: What happens when I place a bounty?
"The question is immediately bumped to the top of the active question list." ~ http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: Did the question really warrant/need a bounty? It's got 2300+ views in 2 days, and 2 non-deleted answers.

Comment: I might have just wanted to reward the answers

Comment: @giacomocasanova If you wanted to do that you should have selected the option that corresponds to that, not the "Draw attention" one.

Comment: Sure, but there's a separate bounty reason just for that, and you haven't even accepted either of the answers. You specifically chose "draw attention".  Your prerogative, IMO - just seems unnecessary at this point in time.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVfkYZmXHAg

Comment: You should really provide a complete list if there is a pattern. For this particular one, @keen should say why, although I would guess it was to stop the comments, which belong in chat if anywhere, not on the question.

Comment: @phantom42 - there are no rules stating where it's "OK" to put a bounty. AT ALL.

Comment: @DVK I didn't say it was against the rules or etiquette. I said I didn't personally see the need for a "draw attention" bounty on this question at this time.

Comment: @phantom42 - he was explicitly TOLD to use the bounty to draw attention by a high level user: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3604/976

Comment: @DVK that other meta question wasn't specifically asking about any question. In fact, the Buffy question didn't even exist at the time. But Richard's answer is correct, IMO. It *is* the right action to take to promote a question. I just don't *personally* see the need to promote a question that is currently pretty healthy.

Comment: @DVK I personally have no inherent problem with the bounty being offered for purposes of promotion. I don't see the need, but that's just me. Why Keen closed it is Keen's reason. I could make a guess or two based on the actions/comments I've seen in the history, but that's all it would be - a guess.

Comment: I stand by my answer. If I want to promote a question with a bounty, it's my right to do so - per the Help Centre "if...you feel a particular question still isn't getting enough attention, adding a bounty may help". It doesn't say when I'm allowed to do it.

Comment: @phantom42 2500 views should give you a badge. That's a reason (if you have 2300 to bump to there). Mind you redditing the question's a lot more effective, as my asnwer on meta stated

Comment: @DVK He was also explicitly TOLD to not use bounties to draw attention by a mod.

Comment: @Keen - If you're referring to your own comment on Richard's answer, that does NOT in any way read to me like "Don't post bounties to bump". Merely an explanation of WHY he wants to do it. Moreover, NOWHERE in the site rules does it say (AFAIK) that you can't use bounties to gather views.

Comment: @DVK I'm not referring to that comment.

Comment: @keen - I'll take your word for that, I didn't see that being stated on the original Meta question. And why was he told not to use bounties? That's a perfectly acceptable reason to use the bounties according to the site rules (which basically there are none). Stupid reason, but not against the rules.

Comment: @DVK - If I was a betting man I'd say it's not the using of bounties (which is perfectly within site rules) but rather the high-seeming frequency of bumps over the past week.  Bounties themselves seem irrelevant; it could have been edits, it could have been tag changes, it just happened to be bounties.  This user has established a pattern of bumping questions and that's the problem, not the mechanism by which the questions are bumped.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - um... NO. Frequent edit bumps are frowned upon because they cause problems for the site. No problems can be caused by bounties, both due to their nature AND the fact that you can't put them too frequently

Comment: @DVK Frequent anything _just_ to cause bumping drowns out the other questions on the front page and is frowned upon, although I don't recall if it's explicitly against the rules.

Comment: @izk bounties happen once a week. Not quite anyone's definition of frequent

Comment: @DVK The point is that from the other comments, it looks like this is more of the same - that he usually uses edits, but this is another tactic for further bumping (not that it makes a whole lot of sense given that you do lose the rep)

Comment: @DVK - Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature

Comment: @Izkata - Wanting to get a views badge is NOT in and out of itself against the site rules. So no, using a bounty is NOT "the same" - the former is doing something detrimental to the site (polluting activity feed AND wasting reviewers time) with great frequency; the latter is once a week non-impactful activity.

Comment: @DVK - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/bounty - "*Users may only have three active bounties at any given time*" - this user has bumped **at least four** questions in the space of a week.  I'm not sure why you're trying to make this be about bounties because it's not - this is a pattern that goes beyond bounties.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - you are on a meta question about locking a VERY SPECIFIC question. Not about locks in general or user's pattern in general. This question had no bad activity on it. The only PROPER answer is "the question was locked because a mode felt like it". Other questions with edit bumps are 100% irrelevant- they WERE locked, and somewhat justifyably so.

Comment: @DVK - no, we're not: "*My questions keep getting locked up whenever I put a bounty on them. How do I deal with this? I feel as though I am being abused or just harassing as a novice.*" - this is explicitly about a pattern in general.  What is the difficulty you have with this?

Comment: @JimmyShelter - lack of ability to express himself clearly on this guy's part (he was only talking about one post locked for bounties, not multiple) doesn't excuse the mod's actions

Comment: @DVK - he said "questions", plural, so no, it wasn't one post.  Until you can admit this any argument you make seems invalid.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - he's also ESL. And given that he posted a SEPARATE meta question after 5/9 lock, this was specifically about 5/13 lock.

Comment: ...and now the poor guy is suspended? :/

Comment: @Martha - He was also abusive and spammed 30+ questions onto a moderator's feed. Arguably he had quite a good case for reversing the lock on his question but he then shot himself in the foot with his later actions. Frankly he needed banning for that but Keen seems to have taken pity on him.

Comment: @Richard: he was wronged and he lashed out in frustration. Totally understandable. A timely apology would've gone a long way... Anyway, I guess I can see that a suspension was in order for his later actions, but it's still an unfortunate situation.

Comment: Thanks to all who defended me during my exile, martha youre too sweet also i wasnt frustrated and lashing out, i thought it would be funny to advertise my blocked question on many of the questions of the one who blocked it; more of a curiosity of what would happen

Answer (score 6):

I kind of see both sides of the issue.

As **phantom42** asks, did the question need a bounty at 2300+ views in two days? Not really, no. But my opinion is completely subjective in light of **Richard**'s point that, technically, the OP is not breaking any of our site's rules. **DVK** also makes several comments that I think are important, in that applying unilateral decisions that affect a user's standing in the community have to be made with objective forethought. Unilateral closures can't be a reaction to personal feelings about a user's (alleged) motives if the user's actions are firmly within the scope of the site's rules, no matter how annoying we may find the user's practice.

But really, what's wrong with aggressively pursuing badges? There's nothing bad about those users who really go after points and badges.

I also see nothing wrong with letting someone know they're pushing the boundaries of the site. True, they may not care what you think, but it's still proactive to say something. Moderator communication and well done warnings can really go a long way in justifying future actions. A unilateral, unexpected smack on the hand does nothing to affect positive change. This is why I disagree with the locking of the OP's question -- what purpose did it ultimately serve?

Bounties are allowed and the site does let us use bounties to bump our questions. Solely because of this I don't think it was a good idea to lock the question, especially unilaterally. Until the rule changes, what constitutes appropriate application of the bounty guidelines (i.e. How often can I bump questions?) is undefined. It's unfair to punish someone with a lock, closure, ban, whatever, under these circumstances.

So, objectively, because I really have no iron in this fire, I want to encourage the moderators to affect change and provide us clarity by either having upper management better explain the current rule for our benefit, or by holding a special SFF.se election re: bounties, or by following the rule as it is -- like the rest of us have to.

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head. Keen seems to have overstepped the mark by locking an objectively valid question, Giacomo then shot himself in the foot by abusively complaining. The fact that he's not **perma-banned** is probably the clearest indication that the moderators recognise that something went wrong *on both sides.*

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature - "*Very frequent bumping with no visible change to the question will probably result in it getting flagged and locked*" - the only question is: do we define this users actions as "very frequent" or not.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - there was no "very frequent" bumping. As my answer proved.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - His "bumping" was **well below** the level of editing and re-editing we see from the top 20 users. The edits he made also seem generally sensible and in line with policy (e.g. to improve the posts he's made).

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look at some of these questions and try to figure out why this is the case, and then if something needs to be done about it:

[Why are Slayers always women and not men?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56093/98)

[Why was the 21st chapter in the early American publications of A Clockwork Orange omitted?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/50660/98)

The first one of these had a bounty on it, and was locked shortly after. I personally don't see anything else suspicious about that question.

The second was locked, because it appeared that edits were being used to bump the question to get it more attention. This isn't appropriate behavior, and thus locking the post seems justified.

As far as I can tell, it seems like the first question should not have been locked, although I would question the need to post a bounty to the question. The second seems justified.

Comment: Agreed. The lock on this particular question seems to lack justification.

Comment: The comments have been removed, as they were getting a bit out of hand. If you'd like to have the discussion in chat, feel free. I'd be willing to participate, if available.

Answer (score 5):

Just for reference - I posted this on Meta (MSO, not here) as a conceptual question.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255060/is-it-ok-to-start-a-bounty-on-the-question-you-asked-to-gain-extra-views

Currently, the only (and upvoted) answer, provided by SO moderator, is that using bounties to "Draw Attention" is fully within the rules.

In other words, the [Buffy question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56093/why-are-slayers-always-women-and-not-men) **should NOT have been locked at all**.

---

As an addendum, I tried to reconstruct what happened to the best of my knowledge:

http://notes.io/3SV

***Short version:***

- user edit-bumped several of his posts. As far as I was able to dig out, of ALL his posts edited in May, **only 5 were edited by him**:

  - 1 post had 1 valid edit; 3 posts had 1 low-quality edit each; 1 post 2 low quality edits.
  - Update: I just ran [Data.SE query for edits](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/194548/questions-edited-by-op?UserId=21674) and [Another for bounties](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/194549/bounties-on-users-own-questions?UserId=21674).

    The user had a total (for all his questions): 4 edits (<= May-10) in May, 2 edits in April, 8 edits in March, 4 in February.

    He also posted a grand total of 4 bounties Feb1-May9 (5 including the one that caused this kerfuffle).
- Keen locked one of those posts and told him not to edit-bump
- He posted a Meta question asking if it's OK, was told "no" BUT was also answered by @Richard that it's OK to use bounties (with no contradictory opinions).
- He bountied another question
- Keen locked the bountied question.
- User melted down, including this meta post and reported ~30 comments on Keen's post since Keen wasn't online and thus obviously unreponsive.

Comment: Hey everyone, I was passing through and this piqued my interest. I'll be digging in and taking a close look at how everything has progressed.

Comment: @AnaHevesi - my best effort of forensic reconstruction: http://notes.io/3SV

Comment: You should have posted your question to meta.SE. Meta.SO is just another per-site meta now.

Comment: @Keen - Yep, I realized that too late. Got sidetracked by seeing [this one on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254956/is-it-ok-to-start-a-bounty-in-a-question-you-have-answered-to-promote-your-asnwe?cb=1) and deciding to post mine as a counterpart question on the spur of the moment.

Comment: @AnaHevesi - I also ran a query to measure just how much the user was "abusing" the system. IMHO, not much. See the edit for the link and #s

Comment: @DVK - By this measure, many users (including all of the top 5 users) score higher for edits and bumps of their questions.

Comment: @Richard - exactly my point

Comment: Seriously? Our moderator worship is now on the level that a factual answer referencing research and SE policy gets downvotes merely because it proves the moderator was wrong?

Comment: I agree that the Buffy question should not have been locked.  However, the user has admitted that they were deliberately bumping questions to get views, and this question is explicitly not with reference to a single specific question, so IMO http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/purposeful-question-bumping-abuse-or-feature seems to outline the appropriate guidelines for dealing with it, and locking of other questions seems appropriate.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - if you're referring to BilltheLizard's answer, it clarifies "**Very frequent** bumping". If you look at the Data Exchange stats in my answer, that bumping wasn't even remotely "very frequent". If not for the crap quality of the edits, they would be commendable.

Comment: @DVK... I didnt meltdown though it is an understandable misconception, i merely wanted to see what would happen if i began advertising my post as a joke

Comment: @giacomocasanova - I was referring to the (reported - I didn't personally observe) 30 comments being posted. As well as rude wording of the original edit of this question we are posting on. Neither of which even remotely made it easy defending you even though the mod was clearly in the wrong.

Comment: @DVK..I do thank you for defending, the rude wording was anger i admit but the 30 ads was a prank not out of anger just to see the results

Answer (score 4):

Keen isn't a user, he's a moderator.  That means that he gets to make decisions and we get to respect them.

I can only speculate as to why this one was locked, but since it was asked only 2 days ago it seems a bit early to be locking it.

Despite that, from looking over your previous questions you do *seem* to have recently acquired something of a habit of bumping.  Examples:

- [Why was the 21st chapter in the early American publications of A Clockwork Orange omitted?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50660/why-was-the-21st-chapter-in-the-early-american-publications-of-a-clockwork-orang)
  asked Feb 23rd, bumped May 9th
- [Are there criteria for being a super hero and does Batman meet them?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50314/is-batman-a-super-hero)
  asked Feb 18th, bumped May 9th
- [Why did Dorian Gray react like this to his portrait?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50425/why-did-dorian-gray-react-like-this-to-his-portrait)
  asked Feb 19th, bumped May 5th

*Please* note that I said "*seem*" here.  I'm not accusing, I'm just saying that there is a pattern here and that this pattern seems to have developed recently, although you as much as admitted that you were just bumping to get extra views in your previous Meta question.

Ultimately only Keen can clarify the reasons for his actions, and all I can add is that you may be doing this in good faith, but on the surface it looks like needless bumping to me too.

Comment: Well, that saved me some typing.  Thanks for the excellently-researched answer.

Comment: The irony that I gave these questions extra views while researching is not lost on me. :)

Comment: Also, from this user's profile: "*please view my clockwork orange question*".

Comment: [tag:book-vs-movie] was added on the May 5th edit

Comment: @Izkata - my bad, I missed that.  I'm removing that comment then.

Comment: -1 for "we get to respect them". Respect is earned, not granted. This specific kerfuffle is the opposite of that.

Comment: I'm glad to know we "get to respect" any moderator *carte blanche* simply because he/she *is a moderator*! Do you feel this way about all elected officials? ;) But seriously, it's disingenuous to tell us we should just blindly respect all mod decisions and then state you're "speculating" as to why the post was locked to begin with. I'm sure you know fully by now, but I feel my point still stands. I don't like being placated and if I object to something, I reserve the right to say so. Objecting isn't wrong. The user profile doesn't bother me, fwiw. He can request, but we can choose not to look.

Comment: @Slytherincess - as far as user profile, I just read on MSO that nearly ANYTHING (including even swear words) are considered OK in a user profile outside explicit racism (That was from SE employee or SO mod). So posting a request to view a question is so far from objectionable it isn't even funny.

Comment: Flippant comment for the sole purpose of opening an answer in a humerous manner gets taken absolutely literally.  Sigh.  Given that a community manager is looking over this sh-tstorm I'm saying nothing more until she reports back.

Comment: "Respect" != "agree".  There's a significant difference.

Comment: @Beofett - Agreed on your point for the most part, but, at the end of the day, I still err on the side of respect very much being earned. I don't know if this matters or not, but I was once a mod at a large site where I put in five years. I do understand it's not easy to mod and that it's a *ton* of work. That aspect of modding I do inherently respect. :)

Comment: @JimmyShelter -- My attempt at humor was not meant to offend, not at all. It was meant as lighthearted, but these things don't always translate. Yes, get back to me when you have the info you want, if you'd still like to.

Comment: @Slytherincess - oh, that's OK.  I'm mostly ignoring this question for now because opinions on either side aren't going to change and I don't see value in confrontation.  I'll just add that all the items seem innocent enough if you view each in isolation but when you put them together I at least see enough to support Keen's decision.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I deal with this?

Start by reading that user's feedback. I posted a comment informing you to not bump the question to get a badge, which was the reason you stated for numerous bumps.  It's abusing the site's mechanisms.  After I shut down bumping on that question, you made several minor edits to other questions that are pretty close to the 2500 views needed to get that badge you were gaming the site to get.  So I quickly shut it down by locking the post.

Jimmy's answer provides a partial timeline of bumps.

Comment: -1 for unsubstantiated claim that using bounties to gain views is "abusing the site's mechanisms". Unless that is stated somewhere in site rules, that's not abuse. It doesn't have detrimental effect on the site unlike multiple edit bumps.

Comment: @DVK - you seem to be completely missing the point here, and Keen said nothing about bounties in his answer, so your -1 seems (1) unsubstantiated, and (2) not in good faith.  It's not the bounties, it's the bumping.

Comment: @jim I will double check but I didn't notice any bumps on that question other than a bounty

Comment: @DVK - I'd also suggest that you not view a single question in isolation but take it in the context of the other questions the user has bumped this past week.

Comment: @jim so those questions should have been locked instead. And 3 edits a week I pretty low . People routinely do much much more.

Comment: @Keen -Almost everything I do here is to get badges and rep., I may even answer a question or two while I'm waiting for my next badge :-).

Comment: @JimmyShelter - I was right and you were wrong. That question had no edits for bumping (one valid content edit and one bounty): http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/56093/revisions . So, either Keen made a mistake and locked the wrong question, or - given the date of the edits vs. the date of the locking - more likely as usual went on a unilateral "I'm a mod and will do whatever I feel necessary" and made up a new rule nobody ever heard about and used that as an excuse to close, as enunciated in this answer

Comment: @dvk - I'm in  agreement on this one. There appears to be no valid reason to close that particular question. Posting a bounty is a perfectly valid way to increase views, indeed it's one of the stated choices.

Comment: @dvk - and there was only a single (and perfectly valid,  to my mind) edit in that question.

Comment: @DVK - I suggest that you re-read my answer and note where I observe that this question was only asked 2 days ago, and that I also felt it was too early to lock it.  Then read on and see the bit where I say "*Despite that, from looking over your previous questions you do seem to have recently acquired something of a habit of bumping*".  As I've said multiple times now, the user has what looks like a bad habit of bumping questions and there is a pattern here.

Comment: @JimmyShelter -  your answer shows 3 edits, none later than 4 days ago. Many well respected users on this site have significantly more edits in their history (4 Copy Editor badges, 42 Strunk&White). At least one of those 3 edits was a genuinely good one.

Comment: @DVK - I'm totally unsure what point you're arguing here.  Yes, you're right, that question was OK, no problem there, and I've said that from the start.  Can you tell me what the difficulty is, please?

Comment: @JimmyShelter - I'm arguing that the mod was 100% wrong in locking that question. Other questions have nothing to do with that.

Comment: @DVK - and I'm not arguing against that; I agree that this question shouldn't have been locked.  However, the user is making an accusation of harrassment against the mod (which is quite a serious accusation) and evidence of a pattern of bumping questions refutes that accusation.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - as far as I'm concerned, even ONE lock without a good reason is harrassment. "With great power...". And this specific mod is quite prone to going off on stuff like that (couple of my questions unilaterally closed by him were later reopened by community). If you want to look into patterns, look into ALL patterns :)